# How long will the "Send Your Name to Mars" chips aboard the Mars Landers and Rovers last?

Tags: mars, probe, rovers, curiosity, perseverance

I'm talking about the Chips NASA has placed on Curiosity, InSight and Perseverance:
[image]

You could enter you name on https://mars.nasa.gov/participate/send-your-name/future and NASA etched your name on one of those chips.
On the image page (https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/24877/send-your-name-placard-attached-to-perseverance/) they say each name was individually stenciled onto the chips by an electron beam. My question is, how long will these names last/be readable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature size is minuscule, but the surface is covered by a ?glass? plate. So no dust abrasion. And while tiny, the letter are large enough to not be erased by radioactivity or UV light. (at about 1 micrometre tall, each letter comprises about 5 million atoms. That's large enough for individual atom losses and displacements to not distort the letters).

So, the names will last as long as the physical structure they are mounted on will last.
It should be good for many thousands, possibly many millions of years.

Realistically, it will last until a relic hunter locates the rover, steals it, and sells it for profit.